# Can this Java program ever print a value other than zero?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a favorite C# program similar to the one below that shows that if two threads share the same memory address for counting (one thread incrementing n times, one thread decrementing n times) you can get a final result other than zero.  As long as n is reasonably large, it's pretty easy to get C# to display some non-zero value between [-n, n].  However, I can't get Java to produce a non-zero result even when increasing the number of threads to 1000 (500 up, 500 down).  Is there some memory model or specification difference wrt C# I'm not aware of that guarantees this program will always yield 0 despite the scheduling or number of cores that I am not aware of?  Would we agree that this program could produce a non-zero value even if we can not prove that experimentally?

(Not:, I found this exact question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200601/threads-and-shared-counters-in-java), but when I run that topic's code I also get zero.)

```
public class Counter
{
  private int _counter = 0;

  Counter() throws Exception
  {
    final int limit = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    Thread add = new Thread()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        for(int i = 0; i<limit; i++)
        {
          _counter++;
        }
      }
    };

    Thread sub = new Thread()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        for(int i = 0; i<limit; i++)
        {
         _counter--;
        }
      }
    };

    add.run();
    sub.run();
    add.join();
    sub.join();

    System.out.println(_counter);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    new Counter();
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean calling `start()` instead of `run()`, otherwise you have no additional threads at all.

Comment: Sometimes I actually don't understand what the heck is going on inside the Java VM while a program of mine is running. The JRE performs several optimizations, and in this case there can be a sort of caching of the value assigned to the integer in every thread (like the variable 'spawning' into multiple copies) with a final 'merge' operation, or who the hell knows... Maybe the threads are not 'native' ones. We should look at the JRE code for your platform :)

Comment: oh dear, just the common start <> run confusion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you've given only runs on a single thread, so will always give a result of 0. If you actually *start* two threads, you can indeed get a non-zero result:

```
// Don't call run(), which is a synchronous call, which doesn't start any threads
// Call start(), which starts a new thread and calls run() *in that thread*.
add.start();
sub.start();
```

On my box in a test run that gave -2146200243.

Comment: Beat me by a minute :\ Curse you Jon Skeet!

Comment: @Jon Ug.  I totally meant to call start.  Thanks for the sanity check.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you really meant `start`, not `run`.

On most common platforms it will very likely produce non zero, because `++`/`--` are not atomic operations in case of multiple cores. On single core/single CPU you will most likely get 0 because `++`/`--` are atomic if compiled to one instruction (`add`/`inc`) but that part depends on JVM.

Check result here: http://ideone.com/IzTT2

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your program is that you are not creating an OS thread, so your program is essentially single threaded. In Java you must call `Thread.start()` to create a new OS thread, not `Thread.run()`. This has to do with a regrettable mistake made in the initial Java API. That mistake is that the designer made `Thread` implement `Runnable`.

```
add.start();
sub.start();
add.join();
sub.join();
```